# Is there a tram-only track similar to railtracks?

Tags: cities-skylines

I consider buying the Snowfall-DLC and yes i know it is rated pretty bad but i WANT these damn trams so I dont have much of a choice. The only thing im wondering about:

Is there a tram-only track, where neither cars nor people, bycicles and trains can walk/drive which looks similar to the train-tracks? I'm asking either for a vanilla thing or for a mod or if it is possible to create a mod like this (I'll do it for myself then). I want to create a layout similar to the city where I live:

[image: Tram in Augbsurg, Germany]

And are there train-like stations or only autogenerated busstop-like stops on the side of the road and again, is it possible to create them as a mod if they dont exist yet?

[image]

**Edit:** and yes I googled but I didnt find a god answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know there are Tram only tracks, without road, under the Tram building options, but I don't think you can put stations on the Tram only tracks.

I don't play with any mods, so I can't say if there is a mod for that or not. Although there seem to be a [large number of Tram mods available on the Steam workshop](http://steamcommunity.com/workshop/browse/?appid=255710&searchtext=Tram&childpublishedfileid=0&browsesort=textsearch&section=home).